# How to move wordpress from one directory over another wordpress install in the root

Tags: html, wordpress

I have wordpress installed in both the root and in another directory(other) on the same domain. I am trying to move the other wordpress into the root and I want to delete the original root wordpress. How do I go about doing this so that I can avoid any problems between the different wordpress databases or any other sort of issues?

Comment: You might want to ask this question in here instead: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ -- These two links may be helpful: http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress | http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the hardway:

1. Copy all your wordpress directory and paste it into the new one.
2. Log into phpMyAdmin (via cpanel or whatever you're using)
3. Select your database,
4. On the left side of the phpmyadmin interface, click on wp_options
   table or click on the browse button next to wp_options table
5. Look for the siteurl field
6. Click on the edit button of the same row
7. Replace the old url with the new one
8. validate
9. Do the same for the home field and replace the old url with the new
   one
10. Click on SQL at the top of the interface
11. Enter this SQL query `UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content =
     REPLACE(post_content, 'www.yoursite.com',
     'www.yoursubdomain.site.com');`
12. Log into your admin panel, go to Settings / General , don't change
     anything, just click on save to let wordpress automatically correct
     other urls.
13. Do the same thing with Settings / Permalinks

You should be set.

Comment: There was still quite a lot of references to the old url even after running searchandreplacedb2. Your method fixed the majority of loose ends, although I could not find a home field in wp_options table. Also, I did not know if you wanted me to do the query in wp_options table or at the top level of the db. So I ran it in both and it did not find any references to the old url. I believe because of my use of searchandreplacedb2 before that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just move all your wordpress files wherever you want and use [searchandreplacedb2](http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) to change all urls in your database to new one(do backups before using this tool), its taken database configuration from your wp-config file.

Example:
sub.example.com moved to example.com.
Set search for `http://sub.example.com` in database and replace with `http://example.com`

If you have any cache type plugins - go in admin and clear it.
There still might be problems, so do backups.

Comment: So as far as the initial wordpress(old) in the root, I can just delete it and there shouldn't be any interference with the wordpress(new) that I want to move into the root?

Comment: There shouldn't be, they using different databases, all you need is to change urls with searchandreplace2 tool or manually with hands(hard way), anyway, do backups in case if anything go wrong.

Comment: This helped but not completely. There was still a decent amount of references to the old url that did not change. Thank you though!